# How to pass JSON into an Azure Function with embedded dynamic content in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

In ADFv2 I'm looking up a date and passing it to an Azure Function.  I can pass just the data like so:

```
@activity('GetLastDateProcessed').output.firstRow.LastDateProcessed
```

However if I embed this into a JSON string like this:

```
{"lastProcessDate":"@activity('GetLastDateProcessed').output.firstRow.LastDateProcessed"}
```

I get this {"lastProcessDate":"@activity('GetLastDateProcessed').output.firstRow.LastDateProcessed"} instead of {"lastProcessDate":"2019-11-13"} as input into function.

Last I've tried to use a parameter with no success also.

```
@concat('{"lastProcessDate":"', string(pipeline().parameters.lastProcessDate), '"}')
```

The problem here is the parameter was not set.  I set the parameter like this:

```
@activity('GetLastDateProcessed').output.firstRow.LastDateProcessed
```

[image]
However this is a default value and is never dynamically updated.  If I can update this string then the @concat method will work, but haven't been able to figure out how to dynamically update a parameter for the pipeline.

Another option could be a pipeline variable, but I don't know how to reference the variable.

How do I concat strings together with dynamic content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by creating a second pipeline.  This is not optimal, but works for people running into this same issue.  Hopefully someone finds a better solution than this!

From the first pipeline I set the second pipelines parameter with this:

```
@activity('GetLastDateProcessed').output.firstRow.LastDateProcessed
```

I named the parameter in the second pipeline lastProcessDate so then this worked:

```
@concat('{"lastProcessDate":"', string(pipeline().parameters.lastProcessDate), '"}')
```

This is not straight forward and can't be how Microsoft is expecting us to solve this!

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are missing is that when you use the at-sign '@' in the json string you should follow it with a curly bracket '{'

In your example it will look something like this:

```
{"lastProcessDate":"@{activity('GetLastDateProcessed').output.firstRow.LastDateProcessed}"}
```

here is the source (found it in the comments):
[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/#:~:text=Azure%20Data%20Factory%20(ADF)%20is,in%20your%20data%20factory%20pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/#:%7E:text=Azure%20Data%20Factory%20(ADF)%20is,in%20your%20data%20factory%20pipelines).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with command.

```json
{
  "storedprocedure":"storedProcName",
  "params":"@{variables('currentDt')}"
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)