# Passing nested parameters into Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to setup a Linked Service in Azure data factory that is calling a REST API. This particular API actually nests the parameters in an array, and I'm having trouble implementing this structure into Azure Data Factory to call the API. Example:

[Example of parameter body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckP6s.png)

Does anyone know of any ways to do this in ADF? I managed to get it to work in Postman by using the raw headers, but I don't see a similar option in ADF.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the body in the linked service. But you can specify it in the Copy activity which is using the linked service.

Have a look at the below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Thank for this reference. I've added the following body into the container:

{
    "datatable":
    {
        "start":0,
        "length": 10000,
        "filters": [
            {
                "name": "Arrival Dates",
                "start": "pipeline().parameters.pDate1",
                "end": "pipeline().parameters.pDate2"
            }
        ],
       "sort": [
            {
              "name": "start_date",
              "order": "ASC"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Is this the correct nomenclature for trying to add dynamic content  (I'm using params)?

Comment: This is not correct. You need to use concat to concatenate the different variables. Something like this : @concat('{ "datatable": { "start":0, "length": 10000, "filters": [ { "name": "Arrival Dates", "start": "',pipeline().parameters.pDate1,'", "end": "',pipeline().parameters.pDate2,'" } ], "sort": [ { "name": "start_date", "order": "ASC" } ] } }'). This is also  documented in the SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255137/how-to-pass-json-into-an-azure-function-with-embedded-dynamic-content-in-azure-d

Comment: Since you've opened another question, kindly mark my response as the correct answer so this can be closed.