# Azure Data Factory - attempting to add params to dynamic content in the body of a REST API request

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I'm attempting to add params to the body of a copy task (connected to a REST API post request as the source). I'm wanting to use dynamic content to do so, but I'm struggling trying to find the real solution for the proper nomenclature. Here's what I have so far.

[copy task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMVKX.png)

[dynamic content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQAOm.png)

{
"datatable":
{
"start":0,
"length": 10000,
"filters": [
{
"name": "Arrival Dates",
"start": "pipeline().parameters.pDate1",
"end": "pipeline().parameters.pDate2"
}
],
"sort": [
{
"name": "start_date",
"order": "ASC"
}
]
}
}

You'll notice that I've added params for dates. Is this the correct nomenclature for trying to add dynamic content? The autocorrect tried to add the @ sign in the beginning of the code block, which will cause the entire thing to error out. I've tried adding it before each parameter, but that isn't actually reading the dynamic values either.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. You need to use concat to concatenate the different variables. Something like this :

```
@concat('{ "datatable": { "start":0, "length": 10000, "filters": [ { "name": "Arrival Dates", "start": "',pipeline().parameters.pDate1,'", "end": "',pipeline().parameters.pDate2,'" } ], "sort": [ { "name": "start_date", "order": "ASC" } ] } }')
```

This is also documented in the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255137/how-to-pass-json-into-an-azure-function-with-embedded-dynamic-content-in-azure-d).